# Audience Restriction is missing from SAML 2 response

Tags: asp.net, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to use the Identity Server with ASP.NET (.NET 4.5.1, MVC project) using WIF and WS-Federation. 
WSO2IS version is 5.0.0

*Disclaimer: I'm new with WSO2IS and ASP.NET too (not with .NET itself) and with the whole identity stuff so perhaps I've omitted something basic.*

The problem is that the audience restriction is missing from the SAML 2 response. Otherwise everything looks fine.

In the identity server management console -> service providers -> [my service provider] -> inbound authentication -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration -> [my issuer] -> edit -> enable audience restriction is checked and my ASP.NET web app url is listed

But this is the response my ASP.NET application gets (audience restriction is missing):

```
<wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:wst=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512\">
<wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    <wst:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1</wst:TokenType>
    <wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID\">_8b7d9425958558c7742bb0cb8e8213e9</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </wst:RequestedAttachedReference>
    <wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">
            <wsse:KeyIdentifier ValueType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID\">_8b7d9425958558c7742bb0cb8e8213e9</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
        </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </wst:RequestedUnattachedReference>
    <wst:Lifetime>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">2014-12-02T11:55:13.190Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">2014-12-02T12:00:13.190Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wst:Lifetime>
    <wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <Assertion xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:samlp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion\" AssertionID=\"_8b7d9425958558c7742bb0cb8e8213e9\" IssueInstant=\"2014-12-02T11:55:13.190Z\" Issuer=\"localhost\" MajorVersion=\"1\" MinorVersion=\"1\">
            <Conditions NotBefore=\"2014-12-02T11:55:13.190Z\" NotOnOrAfter=\"2014-12-02T12:00:13.190Z\"></Conditions>
            <AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationInstant=\"2014-12-02T11:55:13.190Z\" AuthenticationMethod=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:am:password\">
            <Subject>
                <NameIdentifier Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress\">admin</NameIdentifier>
                <SubjectConfirmation>
                    <ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</ConfirmationMethod>
                </SubjectConfirmation>
            </Subject>
            </AuthenticationStatement>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1\"></ds:SignatureMethod>
                    <ds:Reference URI=\"#_8b7d9425958558c7742bb0cb8e8213e9\">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature\"></ds:Transform>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\" PrefixList=\"code ds kind rw saml samlp typens #default xsd xsi\"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1\"></ds:DigestMethod>
                        <ds:DigestValue>cqn2im7M8olMyPuO8BDhQvFlcU8=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>jO/kPk+APtOc/gBUsBcLaM4VIbBGe/l2zKAkqjWxfHhkAOx0aduAEt6CssAeY9PrDB/93hxghNPJvn/VAkHKaCLD4/Dt7CwotZHz0l3UABZZiYoMzrZJmO5eOPjA5MAO52Q9vQ+gqLk/iLZCBskgubPmMswi7eufH8jSZES2/ZY=</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECAwCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxDTALBgNVBAoMBFdTTzIxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWxvY2FsaG9zdDAeFw0xMDAyMTkwNzAyMjZaFw0zNTAyMTMwNzAyMjZaMFUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIDAJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzENMAsGA1UECgwEV1NPMjESMBAGA1UEAwwJbG9jYWxob3N0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUp/oV1vWc8/TkQSiAvTousMzOM4asB2iltr2QKozni5aVFu818MpOLZIr8LMnTzWllJvvaA5RAAdpbECb+48FjbBe0hseUdN5HpwvnH/DW8ZccGvk53I6Orq7hLCv1ZHtuOCokghz/ATrhyPq+QktMfXnRS4HrKGJTzxaCcU7OQIDAQABoxIwEDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBPAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAW5wPR7cr1LAdq+IrR44iQlRG5ITCZXY9hI0PygLP2rHANh+PYfTmxbuOnykNGyhM6FjFLbW2uZHQTY1jMrPprjOrmyK5sjJRO4d1DeGHT/YnIjs9JogRKv4XHECwLtIVdAbIdWHEtVZJyMSktcyysFcvuhPQK8Qc/E/Wq8uHSCo=</ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </Assertion>
    </wst:RequestedSecurityToken>
</wst:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

My one guess is the SAML version is perhaps wrong but I don't see a setting for that.

Also in Tools -> SAML Response Builder I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response Destination="https://localhost/SSOTestMVC" ID="cieicenceonlnooiogijcipfohekehdpdhmefpgk" IssueInstant="2014-12-02T12:40:35.411Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="jfmphpmhlnedheigcgefihafkehcjlmpminchpgg" IssueInstant="2014-12-02T12:40:35.438Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">admin</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2014-12-02T12:45:35.411Z" Recipient="https://localhost/SSOTestMVC"/>
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2014-12-02T12:40:35.438Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-12-02T12:45:35.411Z">
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>localhost</saml2:Audience>
                <saml2:Audience>https://localhost/SSOTestMVC</saml2:Audience>
                <saml2:Audience>https://localhost/SSOTestMVC/</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-12-02T12:40:35.447Z">
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

The audience correct, what I had added to the list.

And here is mey web.config for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </configSections>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.IdentityModel" switchValue="Verbose">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\WIF.xml" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
      <add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://localhost/startersts/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->

    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationType="SampleRequestValidator"/>-->
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>

  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://localhost/SSOTestMVC"/>
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="6bf8e136eb36d4a56ea05c7ae4b9a45b63bf975d" name="localhost"/>
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false"/>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://localhost:9443/passivests" realm="https://localhost/SSOTestMVC" requireHttps="true" reply="https://localhost/SSOTestMVC"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

I searched for setting the SAML version in the web.config suspecting that might be a problem but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to highlight that Identity Server supports for following two profiles.

1. SAML2 SSO Web browser based profile. (SAML2 Assertions are used) More details from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/30/open-source-saml2-sso-identity-provider/)
2. WS-Federation (Passive STS) profile. (SAML Assertion)

Normally ASP.NET is by default supports for 2 profile.  Therefore you are integrating using Passive STS.  It seems to be, in your configuration, you have set the url to passive STS end point `https://localhost:9443/passivests`. If you are using SAML2 profile, Normally you need to set it to `https://localhost:9443/samlsso`

Therefore the configuration that you have done in WSO2IS is not valid. They are related to SAML2 SSO profile. For passive STS you can find the configurations under  `WS-Federation (Passive) Configuration`

However there is a [bug](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2802) in Passive STS that Identity Server does not add audience in to the SAML Assertion.

However, You can avoid the audience validation by setting web.config `<audienceUris mode="Never" />`

Comment: So you are saying that the first method is not supported with ASP.NET?

Comment: As i know, It is not by default with the WIF.  But there are some ways to do it.  Actually i am not much familiar with ASP.NET.  Did you see article about passive STS and WSO2IS   http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/12/configuring-wso2-identity-server-passive-sts-aspnet-client/

Comment: Yes I used that to set up things with ASP.NET. Also it is somewhat outdated: the settings are in different place in v5 and the sample project does not work with .NET 4.5. But I solved that and set mode="Never". passive STS is completely satisfactory but as I understand if audience restriction is not set it can be a security problem.